# Monitoring network latency

Tags: networking, monitoring, mac

We're having some network issues but were not sure when or where the problem is most affecting users, I'd like to ping a bunch of URLs every few minutes and graph the results.

Is there a simple package to do this on Mac?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The application you want is called [Smokeping](http://smokeping.darwinports.com/) (available on DarwinPorts).  Give it a bunch of hostnames/IP addresses to ping, and it gives you pretty RRDTool graphs.

Comment: Well said. :) I love me some Smokeping.

Answer (score 4):

Ping, Smokeping, Pingplotter, etc., etc. aren't the best tools for troubleshooting and identifying network performance problems in my opinion. Any test that relies on the ICMP response from some external host only really tells you about that external host and tells you almost nothing about your own network. In addition, any test that relies on an external host's response to ICMP traffic is unreliable as many routers are configured to ignore ICMP traffic directed to themselves or are configured to give that traffic low priority. Routers are concerned with forwarding real traffic, not with responding to your pings. Looking at a routers response to a ping is very often a red herring.

You're better off using a tool that is comprised of an agent on both ends, sending real data. QCheck comes to mind.

http://www.ixchariot.com/products/datasheets/qcheck.html

Comment: That looks expensive.  I'm willing to bet @Tom doesn't want commercial software.

Comment: QCheck is free.

Comment: So it is.  Their website does look very expensive though, if you know what I mean

Comment: Yeah, their other tools are expensive.

Comment: Who says Smokeping relies on ICMP? http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/probe/index.en.html

Comment: I didn't say Smokeping relies on ICMP. I said that any test that relies on the response of a remote host is only really going to tell you about that remote host, not about your own network. I included my thoughts regarding testing with ICMP because the OP mentioned ping in his question. I should have more clearly delineated my comments in my answer.

Comment: Take the point that pinging a bunch of external services is not actually testing our network, I just want to observe a bunch requests over time to see if I can pickup on any more general trends.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the best package for ping latency monitoring is [Smokeping](http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/). Not sure how easy or difficult it will be to get running on a Mac, but I suspect it wouldn't be all that hard.

Answer (score 1):

Creating artificial operations transactions on a system is not a good way to measure how its working. While the effect is usually so small that they don't change the state of the system being monitored, its very difficult to ensure that your test is representative of real usage.

I'd recommend using something [PastMON](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pastmon/) (the quickest route I found to getting this up and running is using a 32 bit [Centos VM](http://virtualboxes.org/images/centos/)).

Answer (score 0):

ping latency is very dependent on where you ping from obviously, just to showcase this give [just-ping.com](http://just-ping.com/) a shot. You might want to consider not to run a tool like Smokeping from your desktop, because you are really measuring the latency of you ISP with it.